# Java Determine If String Starts With Key In Map

Tags: java, dictionary

I want to determine if a given `String` `startsWith` any key in a `Map`.

The simple solution is to iterate through entire the `keySet`.

```
private static Map<String, String> someMap;

private static void method(String line) {
    for (String key : someMap.keySet()) {
        if (line.startsWith(key)) {
            // do something with someMap.get(key);
        }
    }
}
```

My question is: Is there is a better data structure to handle this problem?

Comment: If you know that the length of `line` is far less than the size of the map, you can check if the first character is a key in the map, then if first two combined is a key, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can't be done directly with an `HashMap`: the problem is that `HashMap` uses an hash calculated on the key to manage its position inside the collection. So there is no way to search for a `String` key which starts with a specific substring since there is no correlation between two similar `String` values and their hashes.

But nothing is lost, if you switch to a `TreeMap<String,String>` the problem can be solved easily. A `TreeMap` is still an associative container but it stores entries by using a red-black tree in a sorted order.

This means that elements inside a `TreeMap` are always sorted. In addition to this it gives you some functionalities like:

- `Map.Entry<K,V> ceilingEntry(K key)`: Returns a key-value mapping associated with the **least key greater than or equal to the given key**, or null if there is no such key.
- `Map.Entry<K,V> floorEntry(K key)`: Returns a key-value mapping associated with the **greatest key less than or equal to the given key**, or null if there is no such key.

Now, not only you can search for a specific key by using a substring of its value, but you also do it in an efficient way. Mind that this works thanks to the implementation of `compareTo` of `String` class.

So your problem becomes trivial:

```
TreeMap<String, Object> map = new TreeMap<String, Object>();

map.put("baz", new Object());
map.put("foo", new Object());
map.put("fooz", new Object());
map.put("fo", new Object());

Map.Entry<String, Object> test = map.ceilingEntry("fo");
bool containsSubStringKey = test != null && test.getKey().startsWith("fo");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TreeMap<String, Object> map = new TreeMap<String, Object>();
map.put("baz", new Object());
map.put("foo", new Object());
map.put("fooz", new Object());
map.put("foor", new Object());
NavigableMap tempMap = list.subMap("foo", true, "fop", false);
```

//This will return a map of keys that start with "foo". true means inclusive and //false exclusive. "fop" is the first key that does not start with "foo"